# bash convert rows into columns in table format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to convert rows into columns in table format.

```
Server Name            : dev1-151vd
  Status                 : DONE
  Begin time             : 2021-12-20 04:30:05.458719-05:00
  End time               : 2021-12-20 04:33:15.549731-05:00

  Server Name            : dev2-152vd
  Status                 : DONE
  Begin time             : 2021-12-20 04:30:05.405746-05:00
  End time               : 2021-12-20 04:30:45.212935-05:00
```

I used the following awk script to transpose rows into columns

```
awk -F":" -v n=4 \
  'BEGIN { x=1; c=0;} 
  ++c <= n && x == 1 {print $1; buf = buf $2 "\n";
       if(c == n) {x = 2; printf buf} next;}
   !/./{c=0;next}
    c <=n {printf "%4s\n", $2}' temp1.txt | \
   paste - - - - | \
   column -t -s "$(printf "\t")"




Server Name                Status                      Begin time                 End time
 dev1-151vd                  DONE                       2021-12-20 04               2021-12-20 04
 dev2-152vd                  DONE                       2021-12-20 04              2021-12-20 04
```

The above o/p doesn't have proper begin time & End time,Please let me know how to get the formatting right so the time is printed appropriately.

Comment: Never do `printf buf` for any input as it'll fail cryptically when your input contains printf formatting chars like `%s`, always do `printf "%s", buf` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this script:

```
awk -F": " -v n=4 \
  'BEGIN { x=1; c=0;} 
  ++c <= n && x == 1 {print $1; buf = buf $2 "\n";
       if(c == n) {x = 2; printf buf} next;}
   !/./{c=0;next}
    c <=n {printf "%4s\n", $2}' 20211222.txt | \
   paste - - - - | \
   column -t -s "$(printf "\t")"
```

Output:

```
Server Name                Status                     Begin time                        End time
dev1-151vd               DONE                       2021-12-20 04:30:05.458719-05:00  2021-12-20 04:33:15.549731-05:00
dev2-152vd               DONE                       2021-12-20 04:30:05.405746-05:00  2021-12-20 04:30:45.212935-05:00
```

Explanation:
In awk, the `-F` option means field-separator. In your code you used a colon to separate columns from one another. However in your input, some lines have more than 1 colon (i.e. your timestamp field alone has 3 colons) therefore awk interprets these as having 5 columns.

The solution is to add a whitespace to your field separator (`": "`), since your input does have a whitespace after the first colon and before your second column.

Comment: How can i convert the output as html file

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NF {
    if ( ++fldNr == 1 ) {
        recNr++
        rec = ""
    }
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    hdr = hdr (fldNr>1 ? OFS : "") tag
    rec = rec (fldNr>1 ? OFS : "") val
    next
}
{
    if ( recNr == 1 ) {
        print hdr
    }
    print rec
    fldNr = 0
}
END { if (fldNr) print rec }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
Server Name  Status  Begin time                        End time
dev1-151vd   DONE    2021-12-20 04:30:05.458719-05:00  2021-12-20 04:33:15.549731-05:00
dev2-152vd   DONE    2021-12-20 04:30:05.405746-05:00  2021-12-20 04:30:45.212935-05:00
```

The above will work no matter how many lines per record you have in your input and whether you have other `:`s or `%s`s or anything else.